# How would I create Dynamic Class Items? C# WinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-design

I want to dynamically add items to a class, but someone may have to help me with my syntax here.

I've got a `ContainerTank` class like this:

```
class ContainerTank {
  double radius;
  public ContainerTank(int diameter) {
    radius = (double)diameter / 2;
  }
  public int Gauge {get;set;}
  public double Volume { get { return (3.1415)*(radius*radius)*Gauge; } }
}
```

Each of our *Sites* can have anything from none to an absurd value of 10 tanks (water tanks, oil tanks, etc.).

I can easily create a Class that using `List<ContainerTank> tankList` to maintain the data in each tank per site, but I'd rather find a way to initialize my class by specifying how many tanks are on a site, then have each tank show up individually.

For example, if I create a new site with 2 tanks, I would have a map to Tank1 and Tank2 (or Tank0 and Tank1 if you want to use zero index).

Why?

For our developers using the code, seeing Tank1 and Tank2 pop up with Visual Studio's IntelliSense would help them when using our control rather than presenting them with a collection.

Mainly, I want to know if it can be done and how I'd implement it.

Comment: What if you want to process "all the tanks"? Is it really worth the inconvenience of not having a collection of those just to get intellisense? Also what if a site only has one tank? Should the developers still see Tank2?

Comment: If a site only has one tank, the site would constructed using `obj = new Site(1)` and intellisense would only display Tank1. If there were NO tanks on a site, it would be constructed using `obj = new Site(0)` and intellisense would not display any tanks. Looking at Adam Robinson's post below, however, it looks like this can not be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. All class members must be specified when the assembly is compiled.

If what you're interested in is purely ease of debugging, it's possible to [write your own debug visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx).